# Laravel Livewire emit work in some component, but not work in another component

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-livewire

i working with laravel 9 livewire, i have 2 blade view and 3 component,

i use 2 monitors, 1 monitor show a-page, 1 monitor show c-page,

component A & B loaded on same page (a-page)

component C loaded different page (c-page)

when i click button call in a-page, component b got refresh,

but when i click button add in c-page, component b do not refresh,

Component A

```
//component a
public function call()
{
    $this->emit('refresh');
}

public function render()
{
    return view('a-page');
}
```

Component B

```
protected $listeners = ['refresh' => 'render'];

public function render()
{
    $data = [
        'cities' => Cities::where('disabled',0)->count(),    
    ]
    return view('b-page', $data);
}
```

Component C

```
//component c
public function add()
{
    $this->emit('refresh');
}

public function render()
{
    return view('c-page');
}
```

a-page.blade.php

```
//a-page.blade.php
<div>
    <button wire:click="call">
        Call
    </button>

    @livewire('b-page');
</div>
```

b-page.blade.php

```
//b-page.blade.php
<div>
    <table>
        //Data Here
    </table>
</div>
```

c-page.blade.php

```
//c-page.blade.php
<div>
    <button wire:click="add">
        Add
    </button>
</div>
```

What i want is,
when i click button call in a-page or button add in c-page. component b get refresh

Comment: What is the problem? / How do you want it to work?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson i'm sorry, i forgot to add. What i want is, when i click button call in a-page or button add in c-page. component b get refresh. thank you for remind me